# Python - Assigning random number to dictionary value?

Tags: python, function, random, dictionary, range

I am currently try to assign a random value to a dictionary. Every time I call *player["enemy_hit"]*, I want it to choose a random value from the range I have provided. Currently it assigns it a single value from the range. Any way around this? Thanks!

```
import random

def easy_difficulty(player):
    player["enemy_hit"] = random.randrange(3, 10)
    return player

def player_main():
    player = {"health" : 100,
              "xp" : 100,
              "strength" : 0,
              "dexterity" : 0,
              "wisdom" : 0,
              "level_req" : None,
              "health_spawn" : None,
              "enemy_hit" : None}
    player = easy_difficulty(player)
    print(player["enemy_hit"])        
    print(player["enemy_hit"]) 
    print(player["enemy_hit"])       
    return player

player_main()

>>> 
3
3
3
>>>
```

Comment: Appreciate all of the answers, I think the class will be most relevant to my needs, although I've never really used them, should be fun/frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

This is a prime example for making your `Player` a class, and `enenmy_hit` a method. See the [Python Tutorial section on classes](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) for more information about how to use classes and objects.

```
import random

class Player(object):

    def __init__(self, health=100, xp=100, strength=0, dexterity=0,
                 wisdom=0, level_req=None, difficulty=1.0):
        """Initialize the player's attributes (health, xp, ...).
        Create a player object with some default values, unless the have
        been specified as keyword arguments.
        """
        self.health = health
        self.xp = xp
        self.strength = strength
        self.dexterity = dexterity
        self.wisdom = wisdom
        self.level_req = level_req
        self.difficulty = difficulty

    def hit(self):
        """This is the method that calculates a hit on the player.
        It uses a difficulty factor `self.difficulty` set when the class
        was instanciated, and multiplies it by some random amount to determine
        the damage taken. That damage then is subtracted from the player's
        health.
        """
        damage_taken = random.randint(1, 10) * self.difficulty
        self.health -= damage_taken
        print "Taken %s damage, down to %s!" % (damage_taken, self.health)


def main():
    player = Player(difficulty=1.5)
    player.hit()
    player.hit()
    player.hit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
Taken 1.5 damage, down to 98.5!
Taken 13.5 damage, down to 85.0!
Taken 15.0 damage, down to 70.0!
```

So by doing something like this

```
newbie = Player(difficulty=0.5)
veteran = Player(difficulty=2.0)
fighter = Player(strength=100, wisdom=10)
wizard = Player(strength=5, wisdom=70)
```

you can take advantage of creating several instances of the same class with different attributes, overriding the defaults set by `Player.__init__()` where necessary.

Comment: Not really, still lots of work to do (what happens if the Player's health drops below zero)? But I tried to put some building blocks in place hoping to steer him in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

Assign a function to `player["enemy_hit"]` which yields a value each time it's called, e.g.

```
player["enemy_hit"] = lambda: random.randrange(3, 10)
```

You can then access it like

```
player["enemy_hit"]()
```

and it will yield a random value.

Answer (score 0):

Your `easy_difficulty` function assigns one random value to `player["enemy_hit"]` every time it's called. You call it only once -- nothing changes between your `print` calls.

You probably want to call `easy_difficulty` before each `print` call.

Answer (score 0):

You execute `easy_difficulty` only once and you just print it three times, try this:

```
player = easy_difficulty(player)
print(player["enemy_hit"])      
player = easy_difficulty(player)  
print(player["enemy_hit"]) 
player = easy_difficulty(player)
print(player["enemy_hit"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're printing the same thing 3 times. You need to call `player_difficulty` again before printing.